# Methods on value types in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, types

I'm reading a "CLR via C#" by Jeffrey Richter and he suggests never define methods in a value type that are intended to change it's behavior cause value types should be immutable (because of boxing/unboxing expenses and sometimes unpredictable behavior).

So, we can define methods in our custom value type only for displaying it's state?

Can You give any other examples where the ability to define methods within a `Struct` is needed?

Comment: what about DateTime ?

Comment: @Mortalus ha yes, saw this right after I finished writing my answer.

Comment: I've already deleted my comment cause it was wrong) Now I see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best example I can think of is the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) struct.

All instance methods on the type are designed to create a new `DateTime` by manipulating the current one (e.g. `AddMinutes`) or get additional information from the current `DateTime` (e.g. `IsDaylightSavingsTime`). It also has a variety of static methods for creating a new instances from various inputs, (e.g. `FromBinary`) or generally manipulating `DateTime` values (e.g. `Compare`)

No method can actually modify the current instance.